# Motivating examples for switch/case in Java

Tags: lesson-ideas, branching

Students first see `switch`/`case` as a second syntax for `if`/`else`, but eventually they should see its strength in creating cascades.  I know of the traditional example of printing a [cumulative song](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_song), like "Twelve Days of Christmas", and below I've placed some code I use to illustrate the difference in use-case between `if` statements and `switch` cases.  It nicely prints out all 108 lines of the song *Alouette* in 44 lines of code.

The only other motivating example I can think of is a graduated tax calculator (based on the US Federal Income Tax), where cascades can be a nice way to approach the problem.

These examples are fine, but it's not enough to get the lightbulb to *flick on* for most of my students.  What I need is a few more motivating examples that really show students why `switch`/`case` is useful.  What other examples show this clearly?

```
    System.out.println("Alouette, gentille alouette,\n"
            + "Alouette, je te plumerai.\n");

    for(int verse = 1; verse <= 8; verse++){
        if(verse == 1){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai la tête.\nJe te plumerai la tête.");
        } else if (verse == 2){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai le bec.\nJe te plumerai le bec.");
        } else if (verse == 3){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai les yeux.\nJe te plumerai les yeux.");
        } else if (verse == 4){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai le cou.\nJe te plumerai le cou.");
        } else if (verse == 5){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai les ailes.\nJe te plumerai les ailes.");
        } else if (verse == 6){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai les pattes.\nJe te plumerai les pattes.");
        } else if (verse == 7){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai la queue.\nJe te plumerai la queue.");
        } else if (verse == 8){
            System.out.println("Je te plumerai le dos.\nJe te plumerai le dos.");
        }

        switch(verse){
            case 8:
                System.out.println("Et le dos! Et le dos!");
            case 7:
                System.out.println("Et la queue! Et la queue!");
            case 6:
                System.out.println("Et les pattes! Et les pattes!");
            case 5:
                System.out.println("Et les ailes! Et les ailes!");
            case 4:
                System.out.println("Et le cou! Et le cou!");
            case 3:
                System.out.println("Et les yeux! Et les yeux!");
            case 2:
                System.out.println("Et le bec! Et le bec!");
            case 1: 
                System.out.println("Et la tête! Et la tête!");
            default: 
                System.out.println("Alouette! Alouette!\n"
                        + "Ah-ah-ah-ah\n");
        }

        System.out.println("Alouette, gentille alouette,\n"
                + "Alouette, je te plumerai.\n");
```

Comment: urrm. why don't you have `break;` in each case? I thought it was necessary...

Comment: The choice about where (and if) to use `break`s is the great strength of the structure. If you put a break in every case, you will be back to an `if`/`else` structure. But if you skip some... try running the code =D

Comment: It will create chains, won't it?

Comment: I could tell you, but that would spoil the surprise.  (SPOILER ALERT: yes, it does.)

Comment: If the students have been introduced to the "clean code" concept, the switch/case construct is easier to read even if there's a `break` for each case. Makes it obvious that it _is_ a multi-branch decision point.

Comment: From a perspective of someone working in the industry: please don't. Just tell them it was a design mistake in the language. Seemed like a good idea at the time, but turned out to be a huge hurdle in everyday lives of poor Java programmers. Your own example is a good illustration for why it is a bad idea: you have repeated the same code over and over. Obviously, the text of the song won't change, but if you used switch with something that could, you'd again, had a problem with propagating the change through the code (possibly not owned by you).

Answer (score 3):

Consider why you might prefer to use a `switch` in a production environment:

1. Fall through processing. The blackjack example given by @Peter is a good example of this because it mirrors how we think about the problem: all of the face cards fall into the same case & the code follows suit. Be careful with this though, it's easy to abuse this to get terser code at the expense of readability
2. Default handlers. Personally, I find this most useful not in a 'single moment of code', but over a series of refinements. For instance, it's common to not have all your logic to handle multiple situations in place when you start coding, but it's also easy to miss a special case that you meant to add later. A default handler is a convenient & concise way to stub out code that you haven't yet gotten to.  Default handlers for that throw an exceptions or log the event can help avoid silent failures & are less likely to get 'coded out' by an mistakenly adding or removing an `if` or `else`.
3. Maintainability. I find it safer to add & remove code from a `switch` statement than an `if / else if / else` block as I'm more likely to accidentally omit an `else` from an `else if` than I am to omit a `break` from a `switch`.
4. As per Joshua Bloch's *Effective Java*: "Switches on enums are good for augmenting external enums types with constant-specific behavior." For example if you cannot change the source for an Operation enum, but need add support for an inverse method:

   ```
   public static Operation inverse(Operation op){
      switch(op){
         case PLUS:   return Operation.MINUS;
         case MINUS:  return Operation.PLUS;
         case TIMES:  return Operation.DIVIDE;
         case DIVIDE: return Operation.TIMES;
      }
   }
   ```
5. Readability. I find a moderately sized `switch` statement easier to grok than an equivalent `if / else if / else` block.

When possible, avoid contrived examples for motivating usage. Instead, show where you (or someone else) used a `switch` & discuss why it was preferable.

Answer (score 2):

The example that instantly comes to mind is Blackjack. See the code excerpt below for an extended example in C (even though it's C, the syntax will pretty much hold true for Java as well):

```
int cardValue(char card)
{
    int aceValue = -1;

    if (card == 'A')
    {
        do
        {
            printf("What value would you like Ace to be?\n");
            printf("Type 1 or 11: ");
            aceValue = GetInt();
        } while (aceValue != 1 && aceValue != 11);
    }

    switch (card)
    {
        case '2':
            return 2;
        case '3':
            return 3;
        case '4':
            return 4;
        case '5':
            return 5;
        case '6':
            return 6;
        case '7':
            return 7;
        case '8':
            return 8;
        case '9':
            return 9;
        case 'T':
        case 'J':
        case 'Q':
        case 'K':
            return 10;
        case 'A':
            return aceValue;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}
```

This function takes in a character corresponding to the card's value. I used a single `char` as the data type for each card, so I needed a function that took in a card's name (i.e. letter) and returned its value. Were I to design this again, I would probably reduce it down to one `return` statement and have a variable represent something like `cardValue` (and in that case I'd need to use `break` statements, which I currently omit thanks to `return`). That said, the `switch` statement is a clear example where you don't want a bunch of `if-else` statements. For the face cards that would be redundant. There's a nice mix of those cases that "fall through" and those that don't.

Using card games where cards share the same value is a fun, but realistic example for students to see the value of a switch statement.

I'll share one other short example where students have to implement a command-line calculator in C and used `switch` to identify which operation to perform. Here's the `switch` from there:

```
    switch (argv[2][0]) {
        case 'x':
            printf("%f\n", numOne * numTwo);
            break;
        case '/':
            printf("%f\n", numOne / numTwo);
            break;
        case '+':
            printf("%f\n", numOne + numTwo);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf("%f\n", numOne - numTwo);
            break;
        case '%':
            mod = numOne - (numTwo * modNum);
            printf("%f\n", mod);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Usage: <operation> must be x, /, +, -, or %%\n");
            return 1;
    }
```

With this example the clarity of the code is made much stronger by virtue of the case statements for each operation. From a readability perspective, it makes it clear how the operations are separated out by showing so visually.